# Display complete jtextarea content into single cell of excel file during export.

Tags: java, swing, export-to-excel, jtextarea, word-wrap

i am developing one desktop application with the functionality of exporting jtable content into an excel file.

Now here is the flow of project code that i am implementing:-

[image: Form with Textarea for remarks and report]

After importing jtable into excel, data is written in this way:- (only single record is in jtable)

[image]

Now here all data is exporting in proper way except OUR REMARKS & CLIENT REPORT.

I have also tried to implement setLineWrap() and setWrapStyleWord() but still its not working.

Here is my code for above functions for OUR REMARKS textarea:-

```
 txtOurRemarks.setLineWrap(true);
 txtOurRemarks.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

Can anyone help me out in this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess the problem is that you have new line characters in your output file. So you would need to replace those characters with a blank character so they appear together on a single line in Excel.